# Framework not found GoogleAppMeasurement for Firebase/AnalyticsWithoutAdIdSupport

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, cocoa, google-analytics

I have this error on Xcode.

I know this question has already been asked several times but I have tried everything.

```
sudo gem install cocoapods -n/usr/local/bin
pod deintegrate
pod clean
pod install --repo-update
```

Clean DerivedData and my project isn't on iCloud.

Please help me.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After `pod deintegrate`, remove `GoogleAppMeasurement.framework` from the Build Settings.

It should not be linked when `GoogleAppMeasurementWithoutAdIDSupport` is used

Comment: Where exactlyy?

Comment: After backing up, Open the `project.pbxproj` in a text editor and search

Comment: There's no `GoogleAppMeasurement.framework` in `project.pbxproj`.


I added screenshots to the OP.

Comment: Oh I see an issue from the screenshot. AnalyticsWithoutAdIdSupport is not compatible with Google-Mobile-Ads.

Comment: I have an "Anomaly Detected (Drop in Users)" in my Google Analytics. I have been looking for the cause for four days. Do you think `Firebase/AnalyticsWithoutAdIdSupport` or `FirebaseAnalytics/WithoutAdIdSupport` may work? By the way, what's the difference?